# Runtime error:dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: dictionary

I iterate thru items of a dictionary "var_dict".
Then as I iterate in a for loop, I need to update the dictionary. 
I understand that is not possible and that triggers the runtime error I experienced.

My question is, do I need to create a different dictionary to store data? As is now, I am trying to use same dictionary with different keys.

I know the problem is related to iteration thru the key and values of a dictionary and attempt to change it. I want to know if the best option in this case if to create a separate dictionary.

```
 for k, v in var_dict.items():
                           match = str(match)
                           match = match.strip("[]")
                           match = match.strip("''")
                           result = [index for index, value in enumerate(v) if match in value]
                           result = str(result)
                           result = result.strip("[]")
                           result = result.strip("'")
                           #====> IF I print(var_dict), at this point I have no error *********  
                           if result == "0":
                               #It means a match between interface on  RP PSE2 model was found; Interface position is on PSE2 architecture
                               print (f'PSE-2 Line cards:{v}     Interfaces on PSE2:{entry}   Interface PortID:{port_id}')
                               port_id = int(port_id)
                               print(port_id)

                               if port_id >= 19:
                                   #print(f'interface:{entry}  portID={port_id}   CPU_POS={port_cpu_pos}    REPLICATION=YES')
                                   if_info = [entry,'PSE2=YES',port_id,port_cpu_pos,'REPLICATION=YES']
                                   var_dict['IF_PSE2'].append(if_info)
                                   #===> *** This is the point that if i attempt to print var_dict, I get the Error during olist(): dictionary changed size during iteration
                               else:
                                   #print(f'interface:{entry},portID={port_id}   CPU_POS={port_cpu_pos}     REPLICATION=NO')
                                   if_info = [entry,'PSE2=YES',port_id,port_cpu_pos,'REPLICATION=NO']
                                   var_dict['IF_PSE2'].append(if_info)
                           else:
                                #it means the interface is on single PSE. No replication is applicable. Just check threshold between incoming and outgoing rate.
                                if_info = [entry,'PSE2=NO',int(port_id),port_cpu_pos,'REPLICATION=NO']

                                var_dict['IF_PSE1'].append(if_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a shallow copy and that allowed me to iterate a dictionary copy and make modifications to the original dictionary. Problem solved. Thanks.

(...)
 temp_var_dict = var_dict.copy()

```
        for k, v in temp_var_dict.items():
```

(...)